# Do we need to use ‘the’ before ‘bottom right’?

Tags: articles

When we say

> Please make sure that you have all the pages. Page numbers are printed **at bottom right** of each page.

do we need to use *the* before *bottom right*?

Comment: Yes. The same happens with *at the top.*

Comment: @Ustanak if you're going to answer, please write an answer. Answering in comments is not useful.

Comment: @Catija Thank you, but I left it as a comment because the answer is too short! But I'll do it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The same happens with *at **the** top*.

Comment: An explanation why this is correct would make for a better answer.